# Unable to install llama-cpp-python Package in Python - Wheel Building Process gets Stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, llama-cpp-python

I’m trying to install the `llama-cpp-python` package in Python, but I’m encountering an issue where the wheel building process gets stuck. Here’s the command I’m using to install the package:

`pip3 install llama-cpp-python`

The process gets stuck at this step:

`Building wheel for llama-cpp-python (pyproject.toml)...`

I’ve tried increasing the verbosity of the output with the `-v` option, but it didn’t provide any additional useful information. I’ve also tried installing an older version of the package, but I encountered the same issue.

I’ve confirmed that I have the latest versions of pip, setuptools, and wheel installed. My system resources (CPU, memory) also seem to be sufficient.

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

1. **Increasing verbosity:** Running `pip install -v llama-cpp-python` to get more details about what’s happening during the installation process.
2. **Installing an older package version:** This was suggested as a potential solution, but it didn’t resolve the issue.
3. **Upgrading pip, setuptools, and wheel:** Ensuring that I have the latest versions of these tools.
   Despite these efforts, I’m still unable to install the `llama-cpp-python` package. Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any suggestions for resolving it?

*My Linux Version is: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS*

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to increase the RAM. I upgraded it to 16GB, and it's working now.